# Why stopping a SwingWorker does stop it immediately?

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

I'm using a SwingWorker to execute some repeatable tasks in background.
This is my Class:

```
public class CMyThread {

    private SwingWorker<Object, Void> taskWorker;
    public volatile boolean threadDone = false;
        
    public CMyThread() {
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        taskWorker.cancel(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        taskWorker = new SwingWorker<Object, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Object doInBackground() {
                while (!isCancelled()) {
                    // SOMETHING TIMECONSUMING THAT NEEDS TO BE DONE REPEATEDLY
                    CUtils.sleep(10000);
                }
                threadDone = true;
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void done() {
            }
        };
        taskWorker.execute();
    }
    
    public void waitThreadToGentlyFinish() { // called when we call destroy() on the servlet
        while (!threadDone) {
            System.out.print("#");
            CUtils.sleep(200);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is called this way:

```
CMyThread myThread = new CMyThread();
myThread.start();
```

Now, at one point I want to gently stop the thread.
So I call

```
myThread.stop();
myThread.waitThreadToGentlyFinish();
```

I'm expecting that the currently running [ACTION] is going to take time to finish, then only it will exit the loop and set the flag 'threadDone' to true. but what I actually see is that it exits the loop immediately and I never see any '#' characters displayed.

There is obviously something wrong in my code but I can't see the obvious.
Any idea guys ?

Comment: OMG! and here is the obvious. Thanks a lot ! cancel(false) makes a much better job. Now I'm wondering how to deal with long sleeps in the loop. Let's imagine that the process is a daily batch job with a ~23h sleep (calculated). Is there a way to tell cancel(false) for the real task but to the exception of the long sleep?

Comment: btw, I did not understand when you say "calling get() in the done()"... what get() ? your other comments are ok. start() and stop() are there because in my real code the class is implementing an interface with those 2 methods and yes CUtils.sleep() does what you expected.

Comment: Clear ! thanks for the explanation. How would you deal with a sleep(23*24*60*1000) in the loop? so that cancel(false) act as cancel(true) on the sleeping part? searching for a trick but couldn't find one :(